# How to use the ansible.runner module on Ubuntu 14.04.5?

Tags: 14.04, python

I tried to `import ansible.runner` in a Python script but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./boot-device.py", line 5, in 
    import ansible.runner
ImportError: No module named runner
```

When I search the `ansible` package, I can not find any file called `runner`.

I have installed `ansible 2.1.1.0-1ppa~trust` and `python 2.7.5-5ubuntu3`.

Which package I need to use Ansible's `runner` module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/14018) at Ansible's GitHub repository about this. The `runner` module does not exist anymore because of backward-incompatible changes in Ansible's Python API. You would have to change your script accordingly as detailed in Ansible's [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/developing_api.html#python-api) about its Python API.

P.S.: I was considering providing actual code for the changes you need to make but that would seem out of scope for Ask Ubuntu and would fit in better at Stack Overflow. If you have questions about Ansible's Python API, you should ask them at Stack Overflow.

Comment: This means the simple runner examples, one can find on the net, are all obsolete?

Comment: @ceving I would imagine so since you can't even import the `runner` module anymore unless you make sure you are using the pre-2.0  version of Ansible's Python API.